# How Long Does fsck_hfs take for a 3TB external HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

I've been running

```
sudo fsck_hfs -fy -S -l /dev/disk2s2
```

for about 12 hours on an external 3TB hard drive.

So far, there's no output.
I'm on a 2011 iMac running High Sierra.
I've looked around, & there doesn't seem to be a verbose option or progress bar for this version of fsck.

Somebody else with a 1 TB HDD said it was running for 20 days.
I feel like I'm stuck and just have to wait, with no idea how long it will take or whether it has encountered an error and stalled or something.

Thank you.

Comment: What’s your end goal here, to stress test read operations?

Answer (score 2):

If it had encountered an errors, it would have printed a message about that error - so the absence of such error messages is a good sign.

Note that you have chosen to use the `-S` parameter, which forces it to read each and every block on the device, which essentially takes much longer than a regular `fsck`. Also note that you have used the ´-l` parameter, which basically means that it will make no repairs.